# About fork-join framework

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join

Being the method `fork();` within `compute()` how come that does not get called another degree of parallelism each time the method `compute()` occurs? Is there a boolean flag perhaps?
**EDIT:**

overriding the method `compute()` of the class RecursiveTask:
(pseudocode)

```
if {array.length<100)
do it
else
divide array by 2;
fork();
int righta = rightArray.compute();
int lefta =(Integer)leftArray.join();
return righta +lefta;
```

So basically this is the `compute()` method which gets called recursively and when `fork()` happens it makes it possible to use parallelism and process that task with another core. However being recursive `fork()` should be called all the times the method gets recursively called. So in the reality it does not happen (there would be no sense). Is it due to a boolean flag that says fork has already been activated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unclear... Can you write some pseudo code showing the code path you don't understand and what you don't understand in it?

Comment: `fork()` is only called if `array.length >= 100`. What more logic do you need?

Comment: I get that. However I want to know only if there is a flag which says "After the first call to fork() don't change CPU anymore for the other calls.)

Comment: What do you mean by "don't change CPU"?

Comment: let's say I have only 2 cores, i get the first time to fork() and that process gets processed by the core number 2. When it gets again to fork() recursively (this time calles from core n.2) it basically gets back to core number 1?

Comment: There is a separation between the number of cores and the number of threads (Java threads are usually mapped directly to OS threads). You can (and do) have lots of threads running on a lot fewer cores.

I believe the ForkJoin framework maps many tasks to a thread pool - so again you can have many more tasks than you do threads.

So no - it won't 'get back to core number 1'.

To help us could you tell us what you expect to happen and what happens. i.e. "with an array of size 1000 fork gets called x times".

Comment: I think it gets divided by 2 recursively the first half is computed by compute() using the current core and the second half by the second core. all the tasks get queued in a double queue(deck) one per each core. Then takes action the following steal-work algorithm. So basically  the fist time that fork() gets called it get that task processed by another core, in order to use parallelism. What happen when fork() gets recalled recursively though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the API

```
 class Fibonacci extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
   final int n;
   Fibonacci(int n) { this.n = n; }
   Integer compute() {
     if (n <= 1)
        return n;
     Fibonacci f1 = new Fibonacci(n - 1);
     f1.fork();
     Fibonacci f2 = new Fibonacci(n - 2);
     return f2.compute() + f1.join();
   }
 }
```

Each time `compute()` is called it will place another computation on another thread (or queue) via fork.  compute continuously forks until there are no more `n` available to process.  At this point compute will wait until the "right" side finishes while `f1.join()` waits for the "left" side to finish.

Whenever `join` is invoked it will actually make the `joining` thread execute lower level tasks (lower on the binary tree) giving you the parallelism you want

Comment: with this "Each time compute() is called it will place another computation on another thread (or queue) via fork." you mean that every computation is done on a separate thread?

Comment: what's the correlation between fork() and multi-core programming?

Comment: The `fork()` will push the task on the fork join work queue for other threads to pick up.  So if you have 5 threads and 10 forks 5 threads will execute and process the 10 forks concurrently (eventually).

Comment: `you mean that every computation is done on a separate thread?` Yes, it very well may be, or can be the current thread.  All depends on the execution.

Comment: so where is the bit that calls the parallel cpu? if fork() does it should not switch cpu each time fork() is called()? thanks a lot.

Comment: Well in Java the CPU is abstracted away and parallelization is thought of on the thread level.  So if you create a ForkJoinPool with the number of threads being `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` the JVM and underlying OS handles the CPU utilization of each running thread.

Comment: So for instance, if you have 4 processors and create 4 threads, there is a good likelyhood that all 4 threads will be executing in parallel on the 4 CPUs without you having to do anything special

Comment: `If fork() does it should not switch cpu each time fork() is called()? thanks a lot.`  Imagine if running a FJPool with 5 threads, and you submit 10 forks, the 5 threads will always pick up the lowest level un-computed task.  And since all tasks are pushed to a queue each thread will be running continuously on separate CPUs until you have no items left on the queue.

Comment: "So for instance, if you have 4 processors and create 4 threads, there is a good likelyhood that all 4 threads will be executing in parallel on the 4 CPUs without you having to do anything special".Is there any possibility to check it with some static methods?(whether the program is using 2 cores or only one?

Comment: I understand that once called fork() there are actually 2 queues(one per core) and when one is empty the one with the empty queue steals jobs to the other core.

Comment: `Is there any possibility to check it with some static methods?(whether the program is using 2 cores or only one?` Unfortunately, not that I know of.  I have inferred based on running times, (do we see an increased of N times with N cores?).

Comment: `I understand that once called fork() there are actually 2 queues(one per core)` There is actually only one queue, and many threads.  When one thread is finished processing it pulls another task from the queue and processes that task (presumably on some CPU maybe the one it is currently on).  So each a FJ worker thread finishes a task it picks another off the queue and runs that task